# Delay before executing method

Tags: java, android, delay

I start an activity from another activity with an intent. This second activity doesn't have any UI, it just initializes some variables and executes automatically a method that makes some processing.

First I start this method calling it from onCreate, but inside the method I use some functionalities that must implement some interfaces, so, I think that these methods are being executed before they have had time to initialize.

So my question is about how to start automatically a method when I start a new activity, but giving to it some time before starting, to let the implemented interfaces initialize.

**UPDATE--**

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private static TextToSpeech tts;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        //...
        SpeechWhenMotion();
    }


    public void SpeechWhenMotion() {
        //...
        tts.speak("Inicializando...", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        //...
    }
```

It doesn't speak because it does not have time to call onInit method from onInitListener.

Comment: could you please add some code, i think you have a conceptual failure in your code.

Comment: Have you looked at the Android [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)?

Comment: you dont need to provide any extra time for the "interfaces to initialize"... something else must be going wrong. Can you post a sample code that can be verified?

Comment: @Hirak I say that about the extra time because I've been looking for this issue and all say the same about that this happens because it has been called first the speak method before the onInit() function.

Comment: @turbo I added code, anyway, as you say, maybe if I call the method in the onResume() method instead of in onCreate(), it has some more time to initialize what it needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your call to `SpeechWhenMotion()` from `onCreate()` to the `onInit()` method from `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`.  The whole point of the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` is that you get the callback to `onInit()` when the initialisation is complete.

You are correct that calling it in onCreate() is too early - you must wait for onInit().